# Can this patent's claims be trivially avoided?

Tags: us8321439

In reference to the patent: [US8321439](https://www.google.com/patents/US8321439)

The three primary claims in this patent all use a hash value that is calculated in a specified way, and the hash is used in the process of looking up a file. However, there is no hash table involved. All that's happening is that the hash value is being used to avoid having to compare the desired name with each name in the directory. The file can be found by comparing the names instead, with an execution cost that is really quite trivial in the scheme of things.

Can it really be this easy to avoid this patent?

Answer (score 1):

Look at each of the patent's claims (especially the independent claims) and if you can avoid even one step in all of the claims, you should avoid infringement **of this patent**. That said, there might easily be other patents you need to consider.

Comment: claims seem to be a moving target when it comes to Microsoft patents. Each time a patent application, or continuation application, is about to be granted, Microsoft files another continuation application - frequently just the day before. Presumably Microsoft intends to continue doing that until the patent expires. Apparently, they're allowed to.

I don't think they can claim my avoidance strategy since scanning a file directory for filenames is clearly prior-art, but it means that anyone going through the claims to see whether they're affected is just wasting their time.